# ExpressionEngine® Answers — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

> **This has been shipped today!** Enjoy your swag, everyone :)
>
> If you still don't have yours and think you should have it by now, please send me an e-mail so I can look into it *instead of leaving a comment here*. :)

---

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!**

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing the love! And thanks to all for building a strong community!! PS> I chose XXL as the biggest option on the form but is it at all possible to get a 3XL? I'm a chunky lil monkey!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, no, @Blatant :\ Contact me via e-mail, and I'll see if we can manage something else :)

Comment: Hey no problem JNat, thanks for coming back to me, I'll add it to my collection of "a bit to small" Tee's, it's my motivation to get on that treadmill!! There's some gold in that pile! 2 x StormTrooper Tee's, a couple of Dark Bunny Movie Tees (the yellow one from 'Moon') and my Elite Dangerous Backers polo to name a few! :D

Comment: @JNat I *think* I remember filling out that form. I've since moved. I'd love to have this swag, so I'm wondering if it's worth checking to see the address you have for me.

Comment: Shoot me an e-mail, and I'll check it for you, @StephenCallender ;)

Comment: Many thanks for the swag - much appreciated :)

Comment: Yesso - it arrived in NL too beginning of august :-) Thanks for the good times on EE-answers